# Silence errors in Python logging

Tags: python, exception

In our system we are using Python Logging module. We had some cases of exceptions while formatting a string to write to the log.
For example:

```
log.info(f"message {di[key]}")
```

Since di has no key, it will raise an exception and will break the flow of the script.
Since this is "only" a log message, I prefer to loose this log message then to break the flow.

In C / C++ I would have used a Macro to be able to catch everything inside a log.info call.

The best solution I could think of is something like this:

```
class SafeLog:
    def __init__(self, log):
        self.log = log

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.log

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        # Log the exception and prevent from propagate
        self.log.exception("Error writing to log")
        return True
```

But it require use `with` everywhere:

```
with SafeLog(log) as safelog:
    safelog.info(f"message {di[key]}")
```

Even though I think that more test cases will have better coverage and reduce such errors, I would still like to know if there is a way to achieve the same in Python?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `log.info(f"message {di.get(key, '<key not found>')}")`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is a good solution, but specific to the dict example. Sadly, it might be any other exception.

Comment: This question doesn't actually have anything to do with logging.

Comment: I'm thinking about "*any other exception*", and, let's use a division by zero as an example, I fail to see a scenario in which you might want to log `log.info(f"Dividing {x/y=}")` *before* checking if that's a valid operation. I'd suggest you (if it's possible in what you're coding) not to log something before checking if it's valid, then `log.info` if it's valid, or a different message with `log.warn` or `log.error` if an exception was captured.

Comment: @blues you are right. Do you have a suggestion for a better title?

Answer (score 0):

As the errors don't have to anything with the logging itself, but the operations you do before the logging, you need something which wraps around your log call without interacting with its arguments. Sadly, the `with` statement or a `try/except` statement are the only ones that I know for doing that. I also thought about decorators but these don't work here because they consume the arguments before calling the wrapper function.

A really not so beautiful solution is wrapping only one `with` statement around bigger chunks of code (maybe all of it if it's in just one module).

Or what about issueing the operation later? But this means a lot of boilerplate code for your different use cases:

```
import logging


class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def division(self, a, b):
        try:
            super().info("%d / %d = %d", a, b, a / b)
        except Exception as exc:
            super().error("Log the exception %s", exc_info=1)


logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log: CustomLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

log.division(5, 1)
```

Last but not least is avoiding exceptions and detecting inconsistencies in your data before you try logging it (doing the operation before the logging). The walrus operator can come in handy here for making assignments and if statements at once:

```
if (dictelement:= dict_.get('keyname', None)):
    log.info(f"something with {dictelement}")
else:
    log.error("Something went wrong...")
```